# Switching audio inputs in real-time speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openai-whisper

I am currently stuck on a project, where I would like to compare (using speech recognition) two different inputs in real time. Input 1 says a command, which is then repeated by Input 2.

The goal is to check that the Input 2 repeats the same phrase, that Input 1 said, ideally as fast as possible.

As the communication is done through Teamspeak / Discord, Input 1 is standard microphone PC input. For Input 2, I have used the VB-audio cable, to re-wire the audio output from Teamspeak / Discord through the virtual cable audio input.

Problem is, I have no idea, how to switch from Input 1 to Input 2 and repeat it in cycles. After each Input finishes the phrase, the word "over" is used, which I believe could simplify the transition.

I am using Whisper voice recognition.

Comment: Which speech recognition library are you using? (For example `SpeechRecognition` from PyPI?) If so, can you list your Microphone devices?